# I can't tell what is being asked

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have been given this problem

> Show that $\Bbb {Z}_m$, with addition modulo $m$, where $m \ge 2$ is an integer, satisfies the closure, associative, and communtative properties, 0 is an additive identity, and for every nonzero $a \in \Bbb {Z}, m-a$ is an additive inverse of a modulo $m$.

Can someone explain what $\Bbb {Z}_m$ is?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $\mathbb{Z}_m$?

Comment: maybe could be a typo so what would $\Bbb Z_m$ be

Comment: The $n$ and $m$ should be the same, or else the notation doesn't really make sense. Regardless, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the collection of integers modulo $n$.

Comment: Can you explain what a collection of integers modulo m means?

Comment: @wolfcall As is said in your question, it is the integers modulo $m$.

Comment: Maybe you recognize the notation $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_m$ is the integers modulo $m$. The quotient set of congruence modulo m is:
$$\mathbb{Z}_m=\{[[0]]_m,[[1]]_m,\ldots,[[m−1]]_m\}$$
Where: $[[x]]_m$ is the [residue class](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Residue_Class) of $x$ modulo $m$.

Equivalently, 
$$\mathbb{Z}_m=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\text{Equivalence relation defined as congruence modulo $m$}}$$

Comment: To make sure I understand this. It is the set of possible remainder from x mod m

Comment: @wolfcall Yes.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks that clears this up.

Comment: one last little thing related to this question is "addition modulo m" the same as "$+_m$"

Comment: @wolfcall Yes. To find $a+_m b$, we add $a$ and $b$ in the ordinary way and then from the sum, remove integral multiples of $m$ in such a way that the reminder $r$ is either $0$ or a positive integer less than $m$.

Comment: thanks teachers really need to match book terminology or the book needs to actually use terminology ... i should be able to solve this now. You have been a great help